# Why does this variable have a value before I do "function MyVar() {}"?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand why this code behaves the way it does:

test.js

```
var User;

console.dir(User);

function User(name) { // User = function(name) { ... seems not to be the same?
    this.name = name;
}
```

node test.js

```
[Function: User]
```

Why does `User` have a value before the `function()` statement?

Comment: possible duplicate of [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Comment: Function declaration statements are treated as if they appear at the very top of the function body, regardless of where they appear in the code.

Comment: Named function definitions are treated differently from function expressions; similarly to `var` statements, they don't take effect at the point they appear in the source code. I'm not sure of the details, and I don't have a standard quote handy, so this is a comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hoisting! http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html

`var` and `function` statements are automatically hoisted to the top of the script!

This allows functions to be used before they are defined, like this:

```
dothis();
function dothis() { alert('wow'); }
```

**edit** `function` statements like this are not affected:

```
myfunc(); // won't work
var myfunc = function() { alert('nope'); }
```

Answer (score 2):

That function is defined at parse time.

Please refer to: [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname?rq=1)